# VPN to my small network, correct approach?

Tags: vpn, design

I would like to know if my approach is correct. I have an ISP->Router and to router 2 servers are connected (Windows and VPN) and a switch with local computers.
People from outside should connect and use my local computers using VPN, is that correctly shown? Also what I mean, when they reach the VPN server, will be able to use the LAN as if they were there - I hope.
[image]

Comment: Based on the extremely limited information in the drawing, there's nothing wrong with what you are proposing.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this drawing, all your network is behind your FW so you just have to allow traffic from external clients to VPN server in port 443 (or whatever). When an external client get a local IP, it's in your interal network. Since you have a router from VPN server to local computers, be sure about routing between VPN IP pool and local clientes network.

Tip: A more secure approach it's to connect your VPN to the FW and create two zones. A DMZ zone for VPN server and trust zone por internal clients. Read a manual from major vendors looking for typical deployment scenarios.

Kind regards.

Comment: I know I am probably asking too much but I am prettz new and the more secure, the better - could you show me how you meant your tip? Where to add what etc. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, this is like "tell me how to construct a building". As I a said, take a device manual from some vendor and read overview sections. It really will help you.